# Guidance in executing conditional statement within a Vue method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following method in Vue:

```
shareSubmit: function (schoolId, schoolName, schoolType) {
  this.$eventBus.$emit('share-school-event', {
    schoolId: schoolId,
    schoolName: schoolName,
    schoolType: 'school/' + schoolType,
    schoolAbbr: ''
  });
},
```

What I'd like to do is set 'schoolAbbr' based on what 'schoolType' is. For example, if schoolType is "college," I'd like to set 'schoolAbbr' to "c."

I've tried this but no luck:

```
shareSubmit: function (schoolId, schoolName, schoolType) {
  this.$eventBus.$emit('share-school-event', {
    schoolId: schoolId,
    schoolName: schoolName,
    schoolType: 'school/' + schoolType,
    if (schoolType == 'college' {
      schoolAbbr: 'c';
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access the schoolType property inside of the same object that it is being defined in. The easier way to do this will be do to place what's going to become schoolType in a variable before the ....$emit(. Then you can use that variable in both places.

````
  var innerSchoolType = 'school/' + schoolType;
  var schoolAbbr = //logic based on innerSchoolType here

  this.$eventBus.$emit('share-school-event', {
    schoolId: schoolId,
    schoolName: schoolName,
    schoolType: innerSchoolType,
    schoolAbbr: schoolAbbr
  });
},```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Spread syntax** in the ES6 like below:

```
shareSubmit: function (schoolId, schoolName, schoolType) {
  this.$eventBus.$emit('share-school-event', {
    schoolId: schoolId,
    schoolName: schoolName,
    schoolType: 'school/' + schoolType,
    ...(schoolType == 'college' ? {schoolAbbr: 'c'}: {}),
  });
},
```